# Does polarization cost energy?

Tags: visible-light, waves, polarization

If we have a polarizing filter orientated so that half the photons of a polarized light source pass through, one half will be absorbed by the filter and the other half will assume the polarization of the filter to be observed on the other side.

Does absorption heat the filter, and is any of this energy involved in some kind of physical process that changes the orientation of photons that pass through?

Comment: Polarizers either absorb blocked light (polaroid, for example) or sometimes they reflect it (wire grid polarizer). The passed light effectively undergoes a quantum measurement; this process does not lose any further energy.

Comment: Thx.Is there some link to an experiment confirming this?